# Anyother function than Get

Tags: optimization

Is there a way to access the variables in $category without using  $category1->getId();

I want something link $category1[0]['id'] or something like that

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
            $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
            $category->load();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with a side note, There's no need to call `load` on a collection. Whenever you use it for, for example, a `foreach` it'll get loaded automatically.

Now for your question. You could call `toArray` on your collection which would return you an array with the items on which you could iterate with an index.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
$category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
$category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");

$categoryArray = $category->toArray();
```